# Installing MongoDB in Windows xp 64-bit

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install mongoDB in Windows xp 64-bit, while executing mongod.exe in terminal it throws "The procedure entry point InitailizeSRWLock could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll" error, how to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need either the 32bit or 64bit "legacy" build of MongoDb for older operating systems. The error you're seeing indicates you've tried to execute a build for newer versions of Windows. The function `InitializeSRWLock` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683483%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) is only available on Windows 7/2008+.

Answer (score -2):

At first ,make sure the mongodb you downloaded is just the suitable one for you system.

Secondly ,it seems that you system needs the KERNEL32.dll.You'd better download the KERNEL32.dll manually and put it into your c:\Windows\System\ directory.

Comment: Download kernel32.dll?